# Using mapState in Vue with pinia is giving me an unexpected character error

Tags: javascript, vue.js, pinia

I've created a state in pinia:

```
export const userStore = defineStore('user', {
  state: () => ({ email: '', loggedIn: false }),
});
```

with a simple component that displays a log in screen if the user isn't logged in:

```
<template>
  <HblLogin v-if="!loggedIn" />
</template>

<script>
import { userStore } from '@/stores/userStore';
import HblLogin from '@/components/hbl/HblLogin.vue';
import { mapState } from 'pinia';

export default {
  name: 'HblHome',
  components: { HblLogin },
  computed() {
    ...mapState(userStore, ['loggedIn']);
  },
};
</script>

<style scoped></style>
```

When I run this and go to the page, I get an error that '...' is unexpected.

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: expected expression, got '...'
```

I don't understand what I'm missing. Anyone know?

I've tried with the spread operator, using an arrow function, and having it as an internal function inside computed

Comment: `computed()` should not be a function.  it should be like an object property `computed: { ...mapState() }`

Comment: Damn. Thank you, yoduh. I went right over that.